# Query to generate matrix table

Tags: sql

I've 2 tables **methods** and **activities**

```
// methods
+---+-------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Goblins    |
| 2  | Valkyrie   |

// activities
+-----------+----+---------------------+------------+------------+
| method_id | id | name                | start      | end        |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 1         | 1  | Attack Village A    | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-02 |
| 1         | 2  | Attack Village B    | 2019-01-03 | 2019-01-04 |
| 2         | 3  | Attach Village A    | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-02 |
```

How can I get a matrix table group by method and month. expected result:

| Method | January | Febuary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Goblins | Attack Village A, Attack Village B |  |
| Valkyrie |  | Attack Village A |

Comment: Unless you have an id in methods there is no way of joining the tables

Comment: @P.Salmon I've update and added id to each table

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

to group by the method first, the method table should have ID as a primary key; then you join the two tables in this way:

```
     Select Method.name as name, Activities.name as Activity, MONTHNAME(Activities.start) as Activity_Method
     From methods as Method join activities as Activities
     Where Method.ID = Activities.method_id
```

you will get this table:
// Activity_Method

+-----------+---------------------+------------+

| name      | Activity            | start      |

+-----------+---------------------+------------+

| Goblins   | Attack Village A    |  January   |

| Goblins   | Attack Village B    |  January   |

| Valkyrie  | Attach Village A    |  February  |

Answer (score 1):

Here I am ignoring the fact that the `start` and `end` period can extend between 2 or more separate months and taking `start` as the base for picking the month:

```
SELECT 
  m.`name` AS Method,
  (CASE WHEN MONTH(a.start)=1 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(a.`name`) ELSE '' END) AS January,
(CASE WHEN MONTH(a.start)=2 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(a.`name`) ELSE '' END) AS Febuary
FROM
`activities` a 
  JOIN methods m 
    ON a.`method_id` = m.`id` 
    GROUP BY a.`method_id`
```

This should produce you your result:

| Method | January | Febuary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Goblins | Attack Village A,Attack Village B |  |
| Valkyrie |  | Attack Village A |